# How to display data in the form of images from the intent process sent using arraylist and parcelable?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, arraylist, android-intent, parcelable

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
    const val EXTRA_USER = "extra_user"
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

    val imgAvatar:CircleImageView = findViewById(R.id.img_dtlavtr)
    val txtName:TextView = findViewById(R.id.txt_names)
    val txtUname:TextView = findViewById(R.id.txt_uname)

    val users = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<User>(EXTRA_USER) as ArrayList<User>
    imgAvatar.setImageResource(users)
    txtName.text
    txtUname.text

}
```

}

It's my first time learning Android Studio and Kotlin,
Above is the second activity DetailActivity.kt, in the section I will display an image (imgAvatar.setImageresource(users)), an error appears
I use arraylist and parcelable to send data sets in the form of images and text
"Type missmatch
Required: Int
Found: kotlin.collection. ArrayList  "

and here's the code for MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
private lateinit var dataName: Array<String>
private lateinit var dataUname: Array<String>
private lateinit var dataAvatar: TypedArray
private var users = arrayListOf<User>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.lv_list)
    adapter = UserAdapter(this)
    listView.adapter = adapter

    prepare()
    addItem()

    listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        _, _, position, _ ->
        //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, users[position].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val detailIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailActivity::class.java)
        detailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_USER, users)
        startActivity(detailIntent)
    }
}

private fun addItem() {
    for (position in dataName.indices) {
        val user = User(
            dataAvatar.getResourceId(position, -1),
            dataName[position],
            dataUname[position]
        )
        users.add(user)
    }
    adapter.users = users
}

private fun prepare() {
    dataName = resources.getStringArray(R.array.name)
    dataUname = resources.getStringArray(R.array.username)
    dataAvatar = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.avatar)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please check the android documentations about imageview [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int))

It only accepts a single resource integer. i.e. you can give image sources such as

```
setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage)
```

`R.drawable.yourImage` actually is an int. That is why exception says you that it expects int however found list.